# Not able to receive expected result in mongodb between collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I'm trying to get a product list with logged user wishlist in the product list itself. I'm trying `$lookup` but not getting the expected result.

**Product Document:**

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6044351794bee8b6e0fce48f"),
    "sku" : "P003474",
    "name" : "Kitchen Wash"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6085584c42ad3c58c5dbc6b7"),
    "sku" : "TS0012",
    "name" : "T-shirt"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("608d20a90e629fcc0d3a93e1"),
    "sku" : "Apple1101",
    "name" : "Green Apple"
}
]
```

**Wishlist Document:**

```
wishlist:

[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("608d8af12b7556c445f5cd87"),
    "product" : ObjectId("6044351794bee8b6e0fce48f"),
    "user" : ObjectId("601fb31a60e0a024143e6ea3"),
    "isLiked" : false
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("608d8bad2b7556c445f5cd88"),
    "product" : ObjectId("6085584c42ad3c58c5dbc6b7"),
    "user" : ObjectId("601fb31a60e0a024143e6ea3"),
    "isLiked" : true
}
]
```

**Expected Result:**

Expected output:

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6044351794bee8b6e0fce48f"),
    "sku" : "P003474",
    "name" : "Kitchen Wash",
    "isLiked": false
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6085584c42ad3c58c5dbc6b7"),
    "sku" : "TS0012",
    "name" : "T-shirt",
    "isLiked": true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("608d20a90e629fcc0d3a93e1"),
    "sku" : "Apple1101",
    "name" : "Green Apple"
}
]
```

The query I'm trying:

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "wishlists",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "product",
      as: "product"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind:"$product"
  }
])
```

Not able to get the above-declared result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` causing the issues, first problem is it will remove document when `product` lookup result empty/[] if you don't specify `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true`, see working behaviour in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tlZeX2l_lMN)
- use `$lookup` with pipeline and match product id and user id condition
- i have changed `as` name to `isLiked` in `$lookup`
- `$addFields` to add `isLiked` parameter it its present, `$arrayElemAt` to get `isLiked` element from first element

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "wishlists",
      let: { product: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              { $expr: { $eq: ["$$product", "$product"] } },
              { user: ObjectId("601fb31a60e0a024143e6ea3") }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "isLiked"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      isLiked: { $arrayElemAt: ["$isLiked.isLiked", 0] }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0XZTX86xP4m)

Comment: +1, I'm receiving the result expected but if I want to filter user in the same query how to do it. "user": ObjectId("601fb31a60e0a024143e6ea3"), right now I have only one user now if more than one user then how to filter the user.

Comment: I'm getting only one document, my case is after the user filter from the product I need all the documents and wishlist I need only filtered user docuemnt.

Comment: I need all product document and matching document from the wishlist with respect to the user can you please help

Comment: okay still confusion just check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0XZTX86xP4m)

Comment: +1 Thanks ya, the last playgroup works perfectly for me, thanks a lot, today I have tried all-time but no luck. you saved me more time today. please update the above-posted answer. Will accept.